# How to download PDF from website and store in %appdata% with Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, file, download, store, appdata

I have a PDF file hosted on a website. I would like my VB.NET program to retrieve the file/download it and store it somewhere in `%appdata%`. This could be in a folder of it's own like `%appdata%/my_program` if you want. How do I achieve this in my VB.NET program?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `WebClient.DownloadFile(Url,LocalPath)` for downloading your PDF file and saving in a local path on your PC. The class is in `System.Net Assembly`.

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to download the file into the same directory as the program, although I can't find a way to save it in the %appdata% directory. Can you please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to download file:

```
    Dim WC As New System.Net.WebClient
    WC.DownloadFile(URL, FileName)
```

or

```
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URL, FileName)
```

To save it in the %appdata% just use :

```
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData
```

or

```
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData
```