# Need help downloading a file into appdata

Tags: vb.net

So I need help downloading a file into `%appdata%`. I am using a code and it doen't work. The code is:

```
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
    ("http://ownage.c12craft.com/xenon/XenonUpdate.jar", _
    "C:\%appdata%\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\XenonUpdate.jar")
```

Can someone fix it?

Comment: Answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539787/how-to-download-pdf-from-website-and-store-in-appdata-with-visual-basic-net/17907584#17907584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%appdata% is not expanded in strings in vb.net

The following should work:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
("http://ownage.c12craft.com/xenon/XenonUpdate.jar", _
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( _
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), _
".minecraft\bin\XenonUpdate.jar")
```